# How to change recipient of GitHub Action failure notification email?

Tags: email, github, github-actions

If a GitHub repo has a GitHub action added, and that action fails, GitHub sends an automated email indicating that failure. How can I change the recipient of that email?

**Background**

My GitHub profile has my personal email address set as the primary email address, and my work email address added as a secondary. In my work's GitHub account I've created a new GitHub repo--one with a GitHub action that executes whenever a push occurs to the GitHub repo. GitHub settings are such that, when a push occurs and the action fails, GitHub sends an automated email indicating the failure. The problem is, when I push from my Git user (using my work email address) and the GitHub action fails, that email is sent to my *personal* email address, rather than my *work* email address. Both my work and I would like to keep all work-related email out of my personal email, if possible.

I'm not sure if the email is being sent to me because I created the repo, because I created the action, or because I initiated the push.

I realize I can *additional* recipients to this notification email, but that's not what I want right now.

---

**Possible Solutions**

- Ideally, I'd like to change the recipient of these emails to any recipient(s) I want. Is that possible? If so, how would I approach that?
- As a fallback, is there a way to simply change the recipient of these emails to my *work* email address, rather than my *personal* email address?

---

**What I've Tried So Far**

- I've asked GitHub support about this, but haven't received a reply.
- Check Settings: In my work repo, I don't seem to have permissions to check the settings of this repo. But I created a similar repo in my personal GitHub account, and was able to check its settings. There is a ‘Notifications’ section and an ‘Actions’ section.  But nothing in either allows me to do what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This worked for me

In your **Github profile notification settings**: https://github.com/settings/notifications

You can set the *default notification email* to one of those which are configured on your account.

#### Here is an example

[image: Example]

There is also an interesting section in your case: *Choosing where your organization’s email notifications are sent*, in the [Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/github/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/setting-up-notifications/configuring-notifications#choosing-where-your-organizations-email-notifications-are-sent) that give more details about this.

Comment: OK awesome, thanks so much.  I had seen the GitHub profile settings to change my default notification email--that wasn't what I wanted.  But that link 'Choosing where your organization’s email notifications are sent' was *precisely* what I was looking for.  I changed it, and it did the trick.  I figured this was an issue that many others must have had, and was probably resolved by now.  Thanks again!